# Rviz receives LaserScan messages but doesn't display them

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there

I made a dummy package that is publishing fake laser scan messages (following this code: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Sensors#Writing_Code_to_Publish_a_LaserScan_Message ).

I use this command to launch my package:

```
roslaunch beginner_tutorials fakeLaserScan.launch
```

Then, I try to display it with:

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

Finally,  I use this command in order to avoid fixed-frame related errors,:

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 map fake_laser_frame 10
```

I set global_frame as "fake_laser_frame" and I add the topic /fakeScan (type LaserScan).
Everything seems to work great, only green checks and I can see the number of receives messages increase.
But I don't see my laser scan displayed ! I tried with a kinect and package "laserscan_kinect", it works.

What am I missing ?

More info:
What I'm trying to do : for the moment, juste learning really. My final is goal to use a Lidar Lite v3 to generate Laser Scan messages.

My code: https://github.com/erenaud3/fakeLaserScan

Screenshot: (I tried, but not enough reputation).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291095/rviz-receives-laserscan-messages-but-doesn%27t-display-them/) by [erenaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/35137/erenaud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarushg](https://answers.ros.org/users/35073/aarushg/) on 2018-05-15**:
For debugging, maybe you can try and see output of `rostopic echo /fakeScan` to check what values are actually being published.

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2018-05-16**:
Hi Erenaud, I prepared a video explaining what could be your problem, but you figured it out before I published. Anyway, here it is just in case it helps you understand some basic ROS concepts.
[video answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cv33X0z_elc&t=616s)

**Comment by [erenaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/35137/erenaud/) on 2018-05-16**:
Wow, you did a great job here ! Thank you for your help ! Don't worry, I'm pretty sure it will help others :)

**Comment by [iBuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/37068/ibuilder/) on 2018-08-27**:
After a short time count> 100, but "range_max = 100". And rviz not show it data.
You must restart the node, after the configured rviz and can seet data shot time.
Or set big limat for range_max or set limit for ranges [i] and intensities [i] less then range_max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, I don't know if it's because I restarted my computer or my eyes were too tired yesterday, but my code is in deed working ! The contrast between background and Laser Scan point is very poor but everything is well displayed.

---

Originally posted by [erenaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/35137/erenaud/) with karma: 28 on 2018-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0